# Did the Office 2013 Update from August 2020 change the vba function autofilter criteria2

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am new here, here is my problem:

I have been using for several functions vba macros in an excel file with password protection. One of the functions is generating a sheet with selcted entries of some different tables. Especially for a certain month via entry for a "monthvalue". My Macro does it with the following code:

```
    Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyList").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=2, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, (monthValue) & "/1/" & Year(Sheets("Jan").Range("A1")))
```

Everything used to work perfectly until the Excel Update couple weeks ago (Beginning of August 2020).
Of course I have other lines of unlocking the password, some copy and paste action and resetting the password and error handling etc. But this section I just shared stopped working with following error code:

> "Run Time Error 1004 AutoFilter method of Range class Failed"

Anybody had this or similar issues?

Anybody knows a solution? (Besides asking all users to roll back the update)

Did Microsoft change the working of this function?
Why would microsoft change the working of this function?
Why me? Why now?...

Thanks in advance.

Akinci

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to construct a date from a string. There are better ways of doing that, e.g. `DateSerial`.

Comment: could you create a minimal reproduceable example of this 'problem'?

Comment: @BigBen I will look into DateSerial

Comment: @Luuk I will try to make a lighter, non-confidential version of it and try to share it here.

Comment: @BigBen On the other hand I don't think the problem arised from string as date / DateSerial issue, because it used to work fine until the last update. (It might be solved there tho)

Comment: As I was creating the minimal reproducable version, I also tried some alternatives starting from DateSerial and ending up in a more elegant solution in my humble opinion. That is using filering like this:
      `Dim MonthCriteria As Integer _        MonthCriteria = (monthValue) + 20 _        Sheets("MySheet").ListObjects("MyList").Range.AutoFilter _        Field:=1, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic, Criteria1:=(MonthCriteria)`

I used month filtrering via enumerator for the Criterias of the 'xlFilterDynamic'. See here: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria]